# Can you place units in an Industrial Complex the turn you place it?

Tags: axis-and-allies

Me and my friends were playing Axis and Allies: spring 1942 and one player placed an industrial complex on a country and then placed their units there, in the same turn. We looked through the entire rule book and we couldn't find it. We looked under the section for placing units and the appendix for Industrial Complex. Are you allowed to to this in Axis and Allies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot use industrial complexes you captured or purchased this turn. You must have missed it, top of [page 22](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/AVL1942_RuleBook.pdf).

> **Phase 5: Mobilize New Units**
>
> Move the newly purchased units from the mobilization zone on the game board to eligible spaces you have controlled since the start of your turn, with the following exceptions (below). **You cannot use industrial complexes that you captured or purchased this turn**.

Comment: And, to my knowledge, this rule is in effect in *all* Axis and Allies variants.

Answer (score 2):

Hey I just wanted to add to this question to say that I have an older version of Axis and Allies purchased back in the 80s.  In my version, it is NOT clear on whether you can place new units in the same space as a newly *purchased* factory.

In fact, here is the exact quote from my version of the rulebook:

'IMPORTANT: you cannot place newly purchased items on industrial complexes that you just captured.'

Here is another quote from Action Sequence 5:

' You cannot place units in a just-captured territory that has an industrial complex on it - you must wait until your next turn to place units there.'

Notice that it DOES NOT mention anything about newly PURCHASED factories, just capturing existing ones.

I have played for years with this rule and it has made for some very interesting games in the first few turns, when everyone is buying up the 3 or 4 extra factories to start a new offensive somewhere strange on the map.

They must have changed this in later versions of the game.  I had no idea until I visited this site.

Answer (score 0):

Just to amplify the rules cited in a previous answer, on any given turn, you can BUILD an industrial complex, or you can build UNITS on a completed one. But you can't do BOTH on the same turn in the same place. It's unreasonable to expect this in any game.

And you have to own the complex at the beginning of your turn to build. If it fell into enemy hands, and you recaptured it, you can't build units there either. (That is, you can't "recapture" and "build" on the same turn in the same place.)

Comment: There's nothing in the rules to suggest that you can't build a complex in one space and build units at another complex in a different space, all on the same turn, which is what you seem to be suggesting here.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I edited to say that you can't do it in the SAME place, Is it Ok now?

Comment: Better, but doesn't really add anything to the existing answer.  The key point is that if you don't own an industrial complex in a space at the start of your turn, you can't build there at the end of the turn.  Things you do in your turn can't change that, and the quoted rule says that pretty clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is at the beginning of the rule book. 
Step one is order units. Step two is repair and pay for said units. So, if a factory is fully damaged, you can repair it, but you can't place it until the next turn.